# document.getElementById().value return undefined in chrome

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="hour" style="display: none">2</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _h = document.getElementById('hour').value
    alert(_h);
</script>
```

Chrome returns `undefined`. What is the problem?

Comment: "In Chrome"? Presumably also a problem in other browsers, or are you saying Chrome is the only one with a problem?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `.value` property applies to form elements (inputs), not divs. The simplest way to get the contents of your div element is with `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("hour").innerText
```

or

```
document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML
```

Comment: document.all is very bad practice. Are you coding for IE5? And I did give a better answer with more up votes. ;)

Comment: You are right, I should use document.getElementById instead.  document.all is not in w3c.

Comment: @neohope: Correct. Chrome and IE support it, but Firefox (for example, doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

divs do not have a value. It is not an input.

You want to use innerHTML or innerText/textContent.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
document.getElementById() method for displaying text on google console.
```

As the other OP said, the div don't have  the .value property.

You can see all HTML DOM property at this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/DEFAULT.ASP

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="hour" style="display: none" value="0" >
```

That should remove the error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34497424)